# Installing Q# in jupyter

Tags: programming, q#

[image]I have followed all steps  described in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/install-guide/qjupyter

But I am unable to get through part 3. It is showing syntax error in Python terminal in Jupyter notebook.
I am not seeing Q# terminal in jupyter notebook (New) folder

Now after so many attempts its showing[image] I am done with this. I think its better to switch to Qiskit.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quatum Computing SE. Could you please add screenshot of the error?

Comment: It sounds like you may have created a Python-language notebook instead of a Q#-language notebook. In the upper-right hand side of the notebook (right next to the "Logout" button), there should be an icon telling you what language your notebook is currently using; for a Python notebook, that should be two interlocking snakes, while for a Q# notebook, it should show a blue and purpse Möbius strip icon. You can select a language for each new Notebook from the "New ↓" menu.

Comment: @ChrisGranade I I don't see the option to start a Q# kernel (only Python 3)

Comment: Looks like a problem with you dotnet installation. What happens when you run `dotnet --version`? I recommend trying to close/reopen the command window.

Comment: This might be related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9567/problems-with-q-installing?rq=1

Comment: Out of curiosity, what folder is `dotnet.exe` installed in to? You can check by running `Get-Command dotnet`. It sounds like your `dotnet.exe` command may not be in the default location that the IQ# global tool is looking for, in which case you can add the `DOTNET_ROOT` environment variable suggested by the error message that you quoted.

Comment: I also just happened to notice that you may be using the x86 version of the .NET Core SDK; can you try with the 64-bit version? You should be able to download from https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/56131147-65ea-47d6-a945-b0296c86e510/44b43b7cb27d55081e650b9a4188a419/dotnet-sdk-3.1.201-win-x64.exe. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @ChrisGranade I am using Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.201 (x64)

Comment: @quanity: Hm, I'm not sure why the screenshot you posted would be showing x86-specific environment variables, then. Would you be willing to share the output of `Get-Command dotnet.exe` and `dotnet --info` to help diagnose? Thanks!

Comment: @quanity same issue I just use it on qbraid now

Answer (score 1):

As @el-capi and @chris-granade mentioned in comments, this looks like a problem with your .NET Core installation. Try the following to get yourself unblocked:

- Remove any existing installation of .NET Core SDK or .NET Core Runtime.
- Install .NET Core 3.1 SDK (x64 or x86 to match your Windows installation) using the links here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/sdk?pivots=os-windows

  > In PowerShell, you can run `[System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem` to see whether you are running 64-bit Windows.
- Open a new command prompt and reinstall the latest version of IQSharp by running:

  ```
  dotnet tool uninstall -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp
  dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp
  dotnet iqsharp install
  ```